# deploy microsoft surface 2.0 application on windows 7 and 8 touch devices

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I have made an application & created installer of it , which is deployed on Samsung Pixelsense 4.0 device & working great. Now I want to deploy same application on window 7/8 touch devices , is it possible if yes , please suggest me  what modification we need to do in my app so that it will install.

regards

Pollen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deploying software that uses Surface 2.0 runtime on Windows, you need to install that middleware.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716

Depending on the multitouch device you're using, you'll need to make changes to your software.  For example, if you're using the generic Windows 7 touch drivers, the SurfaceWindow class will not work.  You'll need to use the regular Window class.